# Maven release plugin and scm plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

If I want to use release plugin with CVS, do I also declare maven-scm-plugin and set it up for my CVS environment ? The release plugin is using maven-scm-providers internally and there is **no way to set up ssh passphrase for instance**.

Both those plugins and their Mojos are using the scm providers but only scm plugin has options to set up the SCM environment in detail. But release plugin doesn't refer to maven-scm-plugin in any way, so that the scm-plugin settings are not utilized in release plugin.

Or is the the convention for release plugin just using userName & password and avoid using stuff like ssh private/public key authorization via passphrase?

Answer (score -1):

Look at [Maven release plugin perform goal configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html)

It does have **username** and **password** parameters

Comment: Did you even read the question, or you just looked at it and spotted username and password :-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood that you want to obtain public key authorization, not get rid of it